# Getting data in an API from a Stored Procedure in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, azure, stored-procedures

So the title may not be the most helpful.. but I am using Microsoft Azure to call a stored procedure

```
mssql.query("EXEC allInfo ?", [meetingID],  
    {
        success: function(results1) {            
            console.log(results1);

            var endOutput2 = request.body.meetingName;

            response.send(statusCodes.OK, endOutput2 ); 
      },
      error: function(err) {
            console.log("error is: " + err);
            response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : err });
      }
    });
```

I know the line

```
var endOutput2 = request.body.meetingName;
```

is not correct.  I am trying to get the result from executing the stored procedure allInfo.  How can I get the data so I can parse it and use it later in the project.  The stored procedure is below.

```
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM ScheduleMe.main_Meeting 
WHERE meetingID = @meetingID;

SELECT * FROM ScheduleMe.date_Time
WHERE meetingID = @meetingID;

END
```

I can get it to output like this(below) but I cannot then just grab meetingName or other variables.

```
[{"meetingID":"899c-64b7-fa94","meetingName":"Test 1","meetingDescription":"test","meetingLength":30,"meetingNotes":null,"hostUserID":"someone@hotmail.com"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result from the result1 variable.

In order to get the first meetingName returned you can do

```
results1[0].meetingName
```

Although it's best to check if the array returned has any elements so this will work better

```
var endOutput2 = null;
if (results1.length)
    endOutput2  = results1[0].meetingName
```

Comment: THANK YOU, I had tried results1.meetingName but it didnt work, adding the [0] worked!

Comment: Keep in mind that if more than one meeting is returned, this will only return the first one.

Comment: I also want to get it from the second SELECT statement.  Here is the output.  I want to get the date/time from both

[ { meetingID: '899c-64b7-fa94',
    meetingDateTime: { Wed, 01 Apr 2015 04:00:00 GMT nanosecondsDelta: 0 },
    setDateTime: false },
  { meetingID: '899c-64b7-fa94',
    meetingDateTime: { Wed, 01 Apr 2015 04:30:00 GMT nanosecondsDelta: 0 },
    setDateTime: false } ]

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with arrays and objects in JavaScript. In the case of getting the meetingDateTime from the second element, you can do results1[1].meetingDateTime.

Comment: Here is more info about [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) in JavaScript 

and [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: results1[1].meetingDateTime did not work... so far everything else has been extremely helpful, thank you